# Find out who included header from project's External dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, dll, lib

I'm creating dll project with Visual Studio. I have quite a lot of files in my External dependencies, and now I'm particularly interested to find out who included `wtypes.h` as it's now have some name conflicts with files from other projects I'm including. Is it a way to find out through which files `wtypes.h` got into my project?

Comment: See [`/showIncludes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/showincludes-list-include-files?view=msvc-160). Or, rename the `wtypes.h` file(s)  temporarily and see where the first error occurs.

Comment: try to run just the preprocessor and inspect the output